# What's the best way to create a validation rule on 'Account' name field that limits trailing periods and all quotes?

Tags: account, validation-rule

I've seen validation rules that exclude special characters but can't figure out how to create a validation rule that would do what I need, which is to exclude quotes and trailing periods. Can one of you rock-stars help?

Comment: You can always edit your post by clicking on the edit link at the bottom left of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `Regular Expression` you will need: `'|\.\z`. Test it out in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/10LzDbIK4N). What this means is: look for all instances of a `'` character OR a `.` character followed by the end of the string.

Your validation rule would then be:

Escape single quotes:

```
REGEX(Name, ".*('|\\.\\z).*")
```

Escape double quotes:

```
REGEX(Name, '.*("|\\.\\z).*')
```

Escape single or double quotes:

```
REGEX(Name, ".*('|\\\"|\\.\\z).*")
```

Comment: Sadly that formula keeps giving me a syntax error, but thank you for posting!

Comment: I think you just need to wrap the expression in quotes.

Comment: Didn't do the trick..this is what I"m trying since I need it to look for quotes and periods.  REGEX(Name, "|\.\z)

Comment: Alright it's a little more complicated, I have updated my answer.